# remove html tags from the json response

Tags: android, html

Hi from the below response want to remove

unwanted tags and blank spaces and want to bold display heading should be bold

can any one help me 
 String termsnconditions=listSalesStageOpportunity.get(position).getTermsnconditions();

Resonse :

```
"<p>Price: Price offered for the above configuration only.<br />
\r\nTax:Above mentioned price is inclusive of custom duty, Excise, Freight up to site and GST.<br />
\r\nLocal levies such as Octroi / Entry tax if any, the same will be at Purchaser’s account.<br />
\r\nValidity: This price is valid for a week from the date of the proposal.<br />
\r\nPayment: 100% Advance<br />
\r\nInstallation  : Genworks Specialist / Representative at your site will give Training and Installation without any additional cost.<br />
\r\nWarranty: 12 Months from the date of installation or 13 Months from the date of Invoice. Warraty will be provided for hardware items only and consumables items are not a part of warranty.</p>"

String terms=termsnconditions.replaceAll("<p>","");
                terms_condition.setText(terms);
```

Comment: Do you want to replace all tags or just p tag ? And also which part of it should be bold ?

Comment: Not only <p><br/>\r\n and spaces and then these Price,Validity,Payment,Installation,Warranty should be bold

Comment: @rootkonda see my comment

Answer (score 0):

```
String terms = "";
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
  terms = (Html.fromHtml(termsnconditions ,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
 } else {
 terms = (Html.fromHtml(termsnconditions ));
}
```

use your string like this

Comment: It should be `termsnconditions` instead of `terms` inside `Html.fromHtml`

Comment: add <b></b> tags to your string

Comment: Price,Validity,Payment,Installation,Warranty should be bold

Comment: use like this <b>Price</b>, <b>Validity</b> and for others also